# Tools to convert Unicode characters

Tags: command-line, unicode

Which tool should I use to convert between various Unicode characters?

Examples:

1. Between various looks: `Normal`, `Ｆｕｌｌｗｉｄｔｈ`.
2. Between one-character and combining versions: `ў` (d1 9e) <-> `ў` (d1 83 cc 86)
3. From usual character to "subscript", "superscript" and "Combining" versions. Normal: `i` Sub: `ᵢ` Super:`ⁱ` Combining:`_ ͥ`

Just `unicode` tools helps, but it is not convenient to use for finding that characters.

P.S. normal to fullwidth onliner: `perl -C63 -pe 's/(.)/((ord $1)<127 and (ord $1)>32) ? chr((ord $1)-0x20+0xFF00) : $1 /ge'`

Comment: this belongs to [softwarerecs.se]